# Contact form not working, made using AJAX, PHP & HTML5

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, contact-form

I am just trying to make a working contact form for my website that will send the form's information to my email when someone wants design work done.

I have never made a contact form that works to send emails before, but I found this tutorial that seemed simple enough. http://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Contact-Form-Web-Application-Tutorial-Ajax-HTML5-PHP

contact.html (Javascript Code)

```
<script>
        function _(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
        function submitForm() {
            _("sBtn").disabled = true;
            _("satus").innerHTML = 'Please wait...';
            var formdata = new FormData();
            formdata.append("c", _("c").value );
            formdata.append("r", _("r").value );
            formdata.append("n", _("n").value );
            formdata.append("e", _("e").value );
            formdata.append("b", _("b").value );
            formdata.append("m", _("m").value );
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.open( "POST", "example_parser.php");
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
                    if(ajax.responseText == "sucess") {
                        _("formContain").innerHTML = '<h2>Thank you '+_("n").value+', our carrier pigeons are in route with your message!</h2>';
                    } else {
                        _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                        _("sBtn").disabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            ajax.send( formdata );
        }
    </script>
```

contact.html (Form Code)

```
<form id="formContain" class="formContain" onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;">
                    <label class="formLabels" for="cName">COMPANY NAME</label>
                    <input class="formInputs" type="text" id="c" placeholder="Your company's name..." required>
                    <label class="formLabels" for="cRole">ROLE</label>
                    <input class="formInputs" type="text" id="r" placeholder="Your role in the company..." required>
                    <label class="formLabels" for="fName">FULL NAME</label>
                    <input class="formInputs" type="text" id="n" placeholder="Your full name..." required>
                    <label class="formLabels" for="cEmail">EMAIL</label>
                    <input class="formInputs" type="email" id="e" placeholder="company@companyname.com..." required>
                    <label class="formLabels" for="cBudget">BUDGET</label>
                    <input class="formInputs" type="text" id="b" placeholder="Your budget..." required>
                    <label class="formLabels" for="cMessage">MESSAGE</label>
                    <textarea class="formMessage" type="text" id="m" placeholder="Your message..." required></textarea>
                    <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" id="sBtn" value="submitForm"><span id="status"></span>
                </form>
```

example_parser.php

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['c']) && isset($_POST['r']) && isset($_POST['n']) && isset($_POST['e']) && isset($_POST['b']) && isset($_POST['m']) ) {
    $c = $_POST['c'];
    $r = $_POST['r'];
    $n = $_POST['n'];
    $e = $_POST['e'];
    $b = $_POST['b'];
    $m = nl2br($_POST['m']);
    $to = "FracturedDesignsOfficial@gmail.com";
    $from = $e;
    $subject = 'New Client Dropped Us A Line!';
    $message = '<style>*{background-color:#1a1a1d;} b{color:#C3073F;} p{color:#8F83B5;}</style><b>Their Company Name:</b> '.c.' <br> <b>Their Role:</b> '.r.' <br> <b>Their Name:</b> '.n.' <br> <b>Their Email:</b> '.e.' <br> <b>Their Budget:</b> '.b.' <br> <p>'.m.'</p>';
    $headers = "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";

    if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "Our carrier pigeons are on strike, we are hard at work taking care of their demands!";
    }
}
?>
```

I was expecting that the  would output "Please wait..." after clicking send message, and that the Javascript & PHP would be run. The page only seems to reload. The only change I can see is instead of http://fractureddesigns.space/contact.html being displayed in the address bar there is http://fractureddesigns.space/contact.html?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a typo in the following line, causing error:

```
_("satus").innerHTML = 'Please wait...';
```

Change it to the following and try:

```
_("status").innerHTML = 'Please wait...';
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have spent the past 5 hours rummaging through this code! I haven't tested it yet, but I am hoping this solves the issue.

Comment: This fixed it! I got the email, I also noticed that I forgot to add $ to the variables I was passing through the email. Was a little confused for a moment as to why they came back as the id's. But it is all working now thank you so much!!! :)

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow.